# Two regression outputs side by side (in R)

Tags: r, regression, stata

I have two regression models (see output below). I want to put the outputs of model1 and model2 side by side, and compare them.

In Stata I would run

> reg colgpa athlete
>   outreg2  colgpa athlete using comparison.tex, append
>   reg colgpa athlete sat
>   outreg2  colgpa athlete sat using comparison.tex, append

and then open *comparison.tex* How do I do it in R using knitr?

I am looking for a command that would output summary(model1) and summary(model2) in the same console.

---

Some background information:

model1:

```
> summary(model1)

Call:
lm(formula = colgpa ~ athlete, data = gpa2)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.66603 -0.43603  0.00397  0.46397  1.61851 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.66603    0.01045 255.212  < 2e-16 ***
athlete     -0.28453    0.04824  -5.898 3.97e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  
0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 0.656 on 4135 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.008343,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.008104 
F-statistic: 34.79 on 1 and 4135 DF,  p-value: 3.966e-09
```

model2:

```
> summary(model2)

Call:
lm(formula = colgpa ~ athlete + sat, data = gpa2)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.84611 -0.38276  0.03056  0.42472  1.76647 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  6.801e-01  7.134e-02   9.533   <2e-16 ***
athlete     -5.061e-02  4.499e-02  -1.125    0.261    
sat          1.917e-03  6.823e-05  28.092   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  
0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 0.6012 on 4134 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1673,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1669 
F-statistic: 415.3 on 2 and 4134 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I can of course type

> summary(model1)
>
> summary(model2)

And let the reader eyeball back and forth. But I want them side by side. This, I can do using `stargazer(model1, model2, title="Regression Results", align=TRUE)` but then I cannot connect it to knitr so that when I knit HTML it produces the output correctly. My goal is namely to go from the Rmd file to a published report directly.

So, to summarize, I am looking for a command that would output summary(model1) and summary(model2) in the same console. This would solve muy problem (although perhaps in an ugly way). If you know a more elegant solution -- perhaps to go from knitr to latex or another approach enterily, my ears are huge.

`stargazer(model1, model2, title="Regression Results", align=TRUE)` outputs

```
% Table created by stargazer v.5.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: Sun, Sep 20, 2015 - 14:56:02
% Requires LaTeX packages: dcolumn 
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
      \caption{Regression Results} 
      \label{} 
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} } 
    \\[-1.8ex]\hline 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
    \cline{2-3} 
    \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{2}{c}{colgpa} \\ 
    \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}\\ 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
     athlete & -0.285^{***} & -0.051 \\ 
      & (0.048) & (0.045) \\ 
      & & \\ 
     sat &  & 0.002^{***} \\ 
      &  & (0.0001) \\ 
      & & \\ 
     Constant & 2.666^{***} & 0.680^{***} \\ 
      & (0.010) & (0.071) \\ 
      & & \\ 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4,137} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4,137} \\ 
    R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.008} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.167} \\ 
    Adjusted R$^{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.008} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.167} \\ 
    Residual Std. Error & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.656 (df = 4135)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.601 (df = 4134)} \\ 
    F Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{34.790$^{***}$ (df = 1; 4135)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{415.289$^{***}$ (df = 2; 4134)} \\ 
    \hline 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    \textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
    \end{tabular} 
    \end{table}
```



Comment: why can't you "connect it to knitr"? And what about adding type="html" to the call to stargazer?

Comment: This is actually offtopic for CV, should be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Where there is already an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26432335/1480928

Answer (score 3):

Here is the content of an R markdown file that does exactly what you want, I believe.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

This is a test. 
```{r, results='asis'}
library(stargazer)
data("trees")
model1 = lm(Height~Girth+Volume,data=trees)
model2 = lm(Height~Girth,data=trees)
stargazer(model1, model2, title="Regression Results", align=TRUE,type="html")
```
````

The key changes are adding `type="html"` to the stargazer call, and setting chunk option results="asis".